# Inno Setup doesn't create a scheduled task

Tags: inno-setup

My installer should install a Windows scheduled task for the application. The task definition is provided in an XML file. Installing the XML task file interactively works fine. But the installer doesn't install the task. Since I don't see its output, I don't know whether an error message is displayed. Windows event log doesn't contain anything.

The Inno Setup task "InstallAutostart" is checked so this should be executed. The files are copied to the installation directory.

Here's the script:

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; Parameters: "/create /tn TClockAutostart /xml ""{app}\StartTClock.xml"""; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Description: "Install task for safe automatic start"; Tasks: InstallAutostart; Check: Not IsWin64
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; Parameters: "/create /tn TClockAutostart /xml ""{app}\StartTClock64.xml"""; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Description: "Install task for safe automatic start"; Tasks: InstallAutostart; Check: IsWin64
```

What's wrong here? How can I debug this?

Comment: Change the entry to `Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/k schtasks.exe /create ...` to see the output.

Comment: An Inno Setup log file would be useful too.